# create table in a different schema

Tags: sql, oracle, roles, privileges

I am trying to create a table on a different schema without using "create any table" privilege. I have an application user/schema.

```
TABLESPACE_NAME                    USEDMB      MAXMB
------------------------------ ---------- ----------
APPLICATION                         .8125         50
```

The application has quota on the tablespace. The user doesn't have quota on any tablespace, and the user's default tablespace is application.

The application schema has existing tables.

```
TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
CUSTOMERS
```

The user can create session and belong to a role app_dev.

```
GRANTEE         OWNER           TABLE_NAME           PRIVILEGE
--------------- --------------- -------------------- ---------------
APP_DEV         APPLICATION     CUSTOMERS            DELETE
APP_DEV         APPLICATION     CUSTOMERS            SELECT


GRANTEE         PRIVILEGE       ADMIN_OPT
--------------- --------------- ---------
APP_DEV         CREATE TABLE    NO

GRANTEE         GRANTED_ROLE
--------------- ------------------
USER            APP_DEV
```

Now i am trying to create a table on application schema with the user "user" but i am getting error:

```
SQL> create table application.test as select * from application.customers;
create table application.test as select * from application.customers
                                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I know the problem can be solved by granting "create any table" but it's a security risk. In addition, creating a procedure on application schema and granting execution to the user wont help, because different kinds of tables will be created by the user and the structure is unknown.

Is there another way?

Thanks,
MJ

Comment: I voted to close this question because it seems a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could, I suppose, create a procedure in `APPLICATION` that accepts a DDL statement and executes it and then grant your user `EXECUTE` privilege on that stored procedure.  But that generally doesn't make sense.  The whole point of having a schema that owns the application tables and separate accounts for users is that it means that your application can be locked (possibly except during upgrades) and user accounts can't mess with the schema model.  The idea that users will be creating tables at runtime seems exceptionally problematic.